# Can I write to and access a file in memory in R?

Tags: r

I am writing tests for an R function that imports an xml file, `settings.xml`.

Currently, when I write a test for functions that depend on the contents of `foo.xml`, including the function `read.settings` in the following example:

```
writeLines("<fee><fi><\fi>\fee>", con = "/tmp/foo.xml")
settings <- read.settings("/tmp/foo.xml")
file.remove("/tmp/foo.xml")
```

But a number of issues have come up related to making the test system-independent. For example, `/tmp/` may not be writeable or an error in `read.settings()` leaves an orphaned file in the test directory, etc. This is a trivial example and I can think of ways around these issues, but I recall such a solution in an answer to a previous question, which I now can not find, in which the `con` is not a file but an object in memory. I am sure that there are many situations in which it would be useful not to actually write a file.

- Is there a way to write and access a pseudo-file that only exists in memory?
- where is the feature documented?
  `?connections` appears to be a good lead, but it is not clear to me how to use the information provided

As follow up (but not to be too open-ended)

- What are the primary uses of such a feature beyond what I described above?
- Are situations in which this feature should not be used?

Comment: Another approach would be to use the [tempfile](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/tempfile.html) function to create a platform-dependent temporary filenames.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a construct that might be helpful. `tempfile()` returns a valid name for a temporary file on any operating system, and the call to `on.exit(unlink())` ensures that the temporary file gets removed, no matter what else happens.

```
test1 <- function() {
    temp <- tempfile()
    on.exit(unlink(temp))
    writeLines("<fee><fi><\fi>\fee>", con = temp)
    settings <- readLines(temp)
    settings
}

test1()
# [1] "<fee><fi><\fi>\fee>"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can turn any string into a connection with `textConnection`.

```
xml.txt <- '<fee><fi><\fi>\fee>'
con <- textConnection(xml.txt)
settings <- read.settings(con)
```

I find string connections useful in situations where the connection functions are handy for what you're doing, but the tasks involved will result in a file on disk sitting open for an extended period. You can use the text connection as buffer.

Note, you can't use `seek` to reset the position of a text connection after reading its contents the way you can with file connections.

Comment: But do be aware that you can only do `readLines()` once from a `textConnection` object.

Comment: I also got stuck here - the `read.settings` function has an argument "inputfile", and has a sanity check `if(file.exists(inputfile))` that now fails, so I can't can change this to ``if(file.exists(inputfile) | exists("inputfile")`. Perhaps this could be a separate question - unless you have a simple answer here?

Comment: @David -- Does `read.settings()` come from some publicly available package, or is it your own creation?

Comment: @David, what you could do is redefine `file.exists` to handle `textConnection`s: `file.exists <- function(...) if (is(list(...)[[1]], 'textConnection')) TRUE else base::file.exists(...)`

Comment: @josh it is a [publicly available](https://ebi-forecast.igb.illinois.edu/redmine/projects/pecan-1-2-5) but very young and narrowly focused suite of packages called "PEcAn" that we develop to support our research on ecosystem functioning ([the read.settings function starts on line 108 here](https://ebi-forecast.igb.illinois.edu/redmine/projects/pecan-1-2-5/repository/entry/common/R/read.settings.R) and was written by my collaborators.)

Comment: The second link isn't working @DavidLeBauer. Would be interested to see a solution like this, akin to `io.StringIO()` in Python

Comment: @Wassadamo yes, that was written before we adopted github. Here are the working links to the [repository](https://github.com/pecanProject/pecan) and to the [read.settings](https://github.com/PecanProject/pecan/blob/develop/base/settings/R/read.settings.R#L47) function