# Does R have an equivalent to python's io for saving file like objects to memory?

Tags: r

In python we can `import io` and then make make a file like object with `some_variable=io.BytesIO()` and then download any type of file to that and interact with it like it were a locally saved file except that it's in memory.  Does R have something like that?  To be clear I'm not asking about what any particular OS does when you save some R object to a temp file.

This is kind of a duplicate of [Can I write to and access a file in memory in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940343/can-i-write-to-and-access-a-file-in-memory-in-r) but that is about 9 years old so maybe the functionality exists now either in base or with a package.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `readBin`.

```
readBin("/path", raw(),  file.info("/path")$size)
```

This is a working example:

```
tfile <- tempfile()
writeBin(serialize(iris, NULL), tfile)
 
x <- readBin(tfile, raw(), file.info(tfile)$size)
unserialize(x)
```

…and you get back your iris data.

This is just an example, but for R objects, it is way more convenient to use `readRDS/saveRDS()`.
However, if the object is an image you want to analyse, `readBin` gives a raw memory representation.

For text files, you should then use:

```
rawToChar(x)
```

but again there are `readLines()`, `read.table()`, etc., for these tasks.